# Greater than symbol on imac not correct

Tags: keyboard

I have a Hungarian keyboard and my greater/less than symbols seem wrong. They are smaller than the ones used for coding.

‹› - this what my keyboard produces

<> and this is what used for coding

I tried every possible combinations but I can't produce the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Hungarian keyboard, `‹` and `›` are typed with `Option + 5` and `Option + 6` respectively. To get `<` and `>`, use `Option + Shift + Y` and `Option + Shift + X` respectively.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much